# Offset of a subobject within a big object

Tags: c++, class

Assume that we have the following object:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
};

struct B : A
{
    A a;
};

B a;

B b;
```

In the `a` and `b` objects we have a subobject of the type `A`. This subobject have some offset within the big object. What does the offset depends on and is it the same among all intances of `B`?

Comment: `sizeof(A)` or what exactly are you asking for ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The C++ standard allows the offset to be implementation defined.
2. All instances of `B` will have the same layout. We can use `offsetof(B, a.a)` to determine that offset.

Comment: Where does the Standard allow us to do so? couldn't you get some reference?

Comment: I would guess that the standard "allows it to be implementation defined" simply by not defining it.

Comment: The only line that I know of that places any restriction on the layout of a non-pod class is: C++ 2011 Section 9.2 Paragraph 14. _Nonstatic data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (11)._